# No query results for model [App\Coin]. - Laravel - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

i got No query results for model [App\Coin]. on my put function. I don't know why ? 
This my my vue js code :

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    cash: {
        codeentry: '',
        description: '',
        cash: '',
    },
    upload: {
        bank: '',
        id: '',
    },
},
methods: {
   let my_data = { upload: this.upload, cash: this.cash.cash }
     axios.put('/updatebank',  my_data)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.etat) {
                    this.upload.id = response.data.etat.id
                    this.upload.bank = response.data.etat.bank
                    this.cash.cash = response.data.etat.cash

                }

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('errors: ', error)
            })
    },
}
});
```

My route :

```
Route::put('/updatebank', 'CoinController@updateBank');
```

My controller:

```
public function updateBank(Request $request)
{
$coin = Coin::findOrFail($request->id);
$coin->bank = ($request->bank - $request->cash);
$coin->save();
}
```

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `post` instead of `put` in the route/axios method?

Comment: @yassinej I gave a response to your previous question

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```
public function updateBank(Request $request)
{
$coin = Coin::findOrFail($request->id);
$coin->bank = ($request->bank - $request->cash);
$coin->save();
return response()->json(['response.data.etat' => $coin]);
}
```